# Can't run mule 3.1.2 on ia64

Tags: mule, itanium

I need run mule 3.1.2 on ia64, but display error below:

```
MULE_HOME is set to /df8003/df8600/esb/mule-standalone-3.1.2
Unable to locate any of the following binaries:
  /df8003/df8600/esb/mule-standalone-3.1.2/lib/boot/exec/wrapper-linux-ia-32
  /df8003/df8600/esb/mule-standalone-3.1.2/lib/boot/exec/wrapper-linux-ia-64 (Found but not executable.)    
  /df8003/df8600/esb/mule-standalone-3.1.2/lib/boot/exec/wrapper
```

I have set the permission.
Any configuration I need make?

Comment: From the logs it seems that the wrapper-linux-ia-64 is found but it can't be executed. What permission does it have?

Comment: Thank you for reply, it have permission 777

Comment: I've just noticed that mule_home is /df8003/df8600/esb/mule-standalone-3.1.2, while mule is looking in here /df8003/df8600/esb/mule-standalone-3.1.2 b/boot/exec/wrapper. Any reason why that might be happening?

Comment: Oh,thanks! you save my life.I think this is the reason, I'll check it.

Comment: Sorry, that's a copy mistake, should be /df8003/df8600/esb/mule-standalone-3.1.2/lib/boot/exec/wrapper-linux-ia-32, still can't run